# How to find the last day of the month from date?

Tags: php, date

How can I get the last day of the month in PHP?

Given:

```
$a_date = "2009-11-23"
```

I want 2009-11-30; and given

```
$a_date = "2009-12-23"
```

I want 2009-12-31.

Answer (score 1008, accepted):

`t` returns the number of days in the month of a given date (see [the docs for `date`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)):

```
$a_date = "2009-11-23";
echo date("Y-m-t", strtotime($a_date));
```

Comment: @Mugunth If you are working with dates 24 years in the future you may run into problems sooner than 2038, however, servers are already moving over to 64-bit architecture which will give us about 292 billion years to correct the problem.

Comment: in procedural -> $date1 = $year.'-'.$month; 
$d = date_create_from_format('Y-m',$date1); 
$last_day = date_format($d, 't');

Comment: With `DateTime` you can do something like this: `(new DateTime('2009-11-23'))->modify('last day of')`

Comment: If you're using Carbon PHP you can use daysInMonth getter

Comment: it is not working if we put `echo date("Y-m-t", strtotime(date('2019-02-29')));`, it should be output `28`. but showing `03-31`

Comment: @Mugunth I am working on a project on RPi3 while dates are beyond 2040 and everything working perfectly.

Comment: @J.Money good software is software which can run on the same machine regardless of what date it is.

Comment: @victor you should bump your comment as answer for the sole reason that it results in readable and understandable code. Clearly using  Y-m-t would work as well but who without looking at the docs would know what "t" is?

Comment: @Himanshu why are you passing on a non-existent date?

Answer (score 159):

I know this is a little bit late but i think there is a more elegant way of doing this with `PHP 5.3+` by using the [DateTime](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class :

```
$date = new DateTime('now');
$date->modify('last day of this month');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: In one line:
$date = new DateTime('last day of this month');

Comment: You might want to add $date->modify('last day of this month')->setTime(23,59,59); if you would like to use this dateTime for comparison where time matters. (This gives you the last second of the month)

Comment: This works: `$date = new DateTime('last day of 2020-2');`

Comment: **NO!!** This only works for the *current month* and *not a specified month as requested by the OP*. Please update your post and I'll remove my down-vote which I'm using as a bookmark to avoid using this code as-is if I need to determine this again in the future and come across this page.

Comment: @John you are wrong. the last day is calculated using the $date object and not the system date. Try it by changing the first line with this : `$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', '1/10/2014');`

Comment: *Look at your post*: **last day of this month**.

Comment: If you were to think or at least try what I asked you to do you would see that _this month_ means the value of the month in the DateTime object not the system's date. If you can't type/run php code this might help : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/290b69fffcf3bc12d684479254c714ee6089b092

Comment: @HannounYassir, this answer is elegant and I have tested it all the way to 2050 including leap years calculations for Feb last day of month, and the results are correct. I am a beginner on PHP, and this has helped tremendously. There is some good magic happening on the background and was wondering, if you could point me to the feature where the modify function recognizes the string 'last day of this month'.

Comment: @CesarB It is something called "Relative Formats". You can read more about it here : https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

Comment: Other option with time: $date->modify('first day of next month midnight'); changes "2038-05-25 14:44:44" to "2038-06-01 00:00:00" for example.

Comment: @John just change the `now` to date anything you want

Comment: The Reason to recommend this answer is that **now *[DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)* interface has more capabilities than before**.

Answer (score 157):

If you're using a 32-bit system, then the strtotime() code will fail after the year 2038 due to the [Year 2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).

For example, on a 32-bit system, this code will echo `1970-01-31`:

```
$a_date = "2040-11-23";
echo date("Y-m-t", strtotime($a_date));
```

If you need your code to support 32-bit systems, then you should instead use the DateTime function:

```
$d = new DateTime('2040-11-23'); 
echo $d->format('Y-m-t');
```

That code will correctly output `2040-11-30` on both a 32-bit or 64-bit system.

Comment: I will be 71 and retired by then, so not a problem for me! j/k But seriously folks -- heed this warning!

Comment: This assumes you are running a 32-bit version of PHP.

Comment: why is this alarming fact about strtotime not mentioned in the php docu http://php.net/manual/de/function.strtotime.php ?

Comment: @Adam It is now, not sure if it was when you checked. http://php.net/manual/de/function.strtotime.php#refsect1-function.strtotime-notes

Comment: As of 2018, the `strtotime` code gives me this result: **2040-11-30**

Comment: Please note that the format function will return a string value, not a DateTime object. If you need the formatted date to be a DateTime object you must create a new instance of DateTime and pass it the string returned from the format function: $d = new DateTime( '2040-11-23' ); $dateString = $d->format( 'Y-m-t' ); $formattedDateTime = new DateTime( $dateString );

Answer (score 97):

There is also the built in PHP function **[cal_days_in_month()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php)**?

> "This function will return the number of days in the month of year for the specified calendar."
>   http://php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.

```
echo cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 11, 2009); 
// = 30
```

Comment: This answer is much simpler and appropriate than the use of strtoTime. I don't see any downsides. To the top you go.

Answer (score 30):

This should work:

```
$week_start = strtotime('last Sunday', time());
$week_end = strtotime('next Sunday', time());

$month_start = strtotime('first day of this month', time());
$month_end = strtotime('last day of this month', time());

$year_start = strtotime('first day of January', time());
$year_end = strtotime('last day of December', time());

echo date('D, M jS Y', $week_start).'<br/>';
echo date('D, M jS Y', $week_end).'<br/>';

echo date('D, M jS Y', $month_start).'<br/>';
echo date('D, M jS Y', $month_end).'<br/>';

echo date('D, M jS Y', $year_start).'<br/>';
echo date('D, M jS Y', $year_end).'<br/>';
```

Answer (score 29):

The most elegant for me is using [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)

I wonder I do not see [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), one-liner

```
$lastDay = \DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", "2009-11-23")->format("Y-m-t");
```

Comment: I agree. This solution (DateTime class) is much better than using the old datetime functions.

Comment: I had to look in php documentation to understand why it works, but yes, is the most elegant solution

Answer (score 20):

Try this , if you are using PHP 5.3+,

```
$a_date = "2009-11-23";
$date = new DateTime($a_date);
$date->modify('last day of this month');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

For finding next month last date, modify as follows,

```
 $date->modify('last day of 1 month');
 echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

and so on..

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Just to complement your answer, you can also use it like this `$date = new DateTime('last day of 2022-06');`.

Answer (score 17):

You could create a date for the first of the next month, and then use `strtotime("-1 day", $firstOfNextMonth)`

Comment: an alternative method using the same approach is to give mktime the 0th day of the next month `mktime(0, 0, 0, $month+1, 0, $year);`

Comment: As to me, usage of `strtotime()` and `mktime()` is discouraged bec. of known bugs like date determination on the edge of the months and leap year calaculations. Since `DateTime` is available, you should use this class to avoid any problems in future. Like said many times before me, both these function `strtotime()` and `mktime()` will fail after 2038. That's why I downvoted ...

Comment: @PaulT.Rawkeen This answer is more than 4 years old. As with anything on the internet, age should be a factor when gauging relevance and usefulness. Further more, IMHO, the halving time for anything related to technology is particularly short.

Comment: @nikc.org I agree, especially regarding time of life for all technical  solutions and ways of solving problems. In this particular case, answer has relatively good number of upvotes and probably, someone (_junior programmer_) will consider this answer as acceptable solution bec. it is short and elegant :) and he will probably get the expected result, but as time goes by, this way of solving such kind of problems becomes tricky and we _should_ warn about such facts when its possible. _Kind regards_.

Answer (score 16):

You can find last day of the month several ways. But simply you can do this using PHP [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.I'd imagine your final code would look something like this:

```
$a_date = "2009-11-23";
echo date('Y-m-t',strtotime($a_date));
```

[Live Demo](https://eval.in/735025)

But If you are using PHP >= 5.2 I strongly suggest you use the new DateTime object. For example like below:

```
$a_date = "2009-11-23";
$date = new DateTime($a_date);
$date->modify('last day of this month');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

[Live Demo](https://eval.in/735024)

Also, you can solve this using your own function like below:

```
/**
 * Last date of a month of a year
 *
 * @param[in] $date - Integer. Default = Current Month
 *
 * @return Last date of the month and year in yyyy-mm-dd format
 */
function last_day_of_the_month($date = '')
{
    $month  = date('m', strtotime($date));
    $year   = date('Y', strtotime($date));
    $result = strtotime("{$year}-{$month}-01");
    $result = strtotime('-1 second', strtotime('+1 month', $result));

    return date('Y-m-d', $result);
}

$a_date = "2009-11-23";
echo last_day_of_the_month($a_date);
```

Comment: FYI, the live demo links do not work anymore.

Answer (score 11):

Your solution is here..

```
$lastday = date('t',strtotime('today'));
```

Comment: this gives `31` for `September` which as you know that's not correct.

Answer (score 9):

Nowadays DateTime does this quite conveniently if you have month and year you can

```
$date = new DateTime('last day of '.$year.'-'.$month);
```

From another DateTime object that would be

```
$date = new DateTime('last day of '.$otherdate->format('Y-m'));
```

Answer (score 7):

If you use the [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) API extension for PHP DateTime, you can get the last day of the month with:

```
$date = Carbon::now();
$date->addMonth();
$date->day = 0;
echo $date->toDateString(); // use toDateTimeString() to get date and time
```

Comment: Actually, if you set day to -1 it will get the last but one. So you must set day to 0 in order to get the last day. `$date->day = 0;`

Comment: thank you @GiovanneAfonso that is correct. I set the day to 0 and tested the answer.

Comment: If you are using Carbon, a one-liner approach is to use: Carbon::Now()->endOfMonth(). However, endOfMonth() is a modifier, so use "clone" if you have an existing variable holding a Carbon date (or the date will be modified).

Answer (score 5):

[Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) API extension for PHP DateTime

```
Carbon::parse("2009-11-23")->lastOfMonth()->day;
```

or

```
Carbon::createFromDate(2009, 11, 23)->lastOfMonth()->day;
```

will return

```
30
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting Carbon library.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use it with datetime

```
$date = new \DateTime();
$nbrDay = $date->format('t');
$lastDay = $date->format('Y-m-t');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$date1 = $year.'-'.$month; 
$d = date_create_from_format('Y-m',$date1); 
$last_day = date_format($d, 't');
```

Answer (score 3):

> If you have a month wise get the last date of the month then,

```
public function getLastDateOfMonth($month)
    {
        $date = date('Y').'-'.$month.'-01';  //make date of month 
        return date('t', strtotime($date)); 
    }

$this->getLastDateOfMonth(01); //31
```

Answer (score 3):

2 lines code and you are done:

```
$oDate = new DateTime("2019-11-23");

// now your date object has been updated with last day of month    
$oDate->setDate($oDate->format("Y"),$oDate->format("m"),$oDate->format("t"));

// or to just echo you can skip the above line using this
echo $oDate->format("Y-m-t");
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Zend_Date it's pretty easy:

```
$date->setDay($date->get(Zend_Date::MONTH_DAYS));
```

Answer (score 2):

An other way using **mktime** and not date('t') :

```
$dateStart= date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, 10, 1, 2016)); //2016-10-01
$dateEnd = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 2016)); //This will return the last day of october, 2016-10-31 :)
```

So this way it calculates either if it is 31,30 or 29

Answer (score 2):

**I am using strtotime with cal_days_in_month as following:**

```
$date_at_last_of_month=date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2020-4-1
+'.(cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,4,2020)-1).' day'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete function:

```
public function get_number_of_days_in_month($month, $year) {
    // Using first day of the month, it doesn't really matter
    $date = $year."-".$month."-1";
    return date("t", strtotime($date));
}
```

This would output following:

```
echo get_number_of_days_in_month(2,2014);
```

Output: 28

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to get last day of month.

```
//to get last day of current month
echo date("t", strtotime('now'));

//to get last day from specific date
$date = "2014-07-24";
echo date("t", strtotime($date));

//to get last day from specific date by calendar
$date = "2014-07-24";
$dateArr=explode('-',$date);
echo cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $dateArr[1], $dateArr[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am late but there are a handful of easy ways to do this as mentioned:

```
$days = date("t");
$days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, date('m'), date('Y'));
$days = date("j",mktime (date("H"),date("i"),date("s"),(date("n")+1),0,date("Y")));
```

Using mktime() is my go to for complete control over all aspects of time...
I.E.

```
echo "<br> ".date("Y-n-j",mktime (date("H"),date("i"),date("s"),(11+1),0,2009));
```

Setting the day to 0 and moving your month up 1 will give you the last day of the previous month. 0 and negative numbers have the similar affect in the different arguements.
[PHP: mktime - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)

As a few have said strtotime isn't the most solid way to go and little if none are as easily versatile.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to go back few months you can do something like this as well.

```
 $list = [
        0, 1, 2, 3
    ];

    $date = new \Datetime();
    $dates = [];
    foreach($list as $item)
    {

        $set = clone $date;
        $set->modify("-$item month ");
       $dates[] = $set->modify("last day of this month");
       
    }
    return $dates;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have wrapped it in my date time helper class here 
https://github.com/normandqq/Date-Time-Helper
using 
    `$dateLastDay = Model_DTHpr::getLastDayOfTheMonth();`

And it is done

Answer (score 0):

```
    $startDate = '2011-12-01';
    $endDate = date('Y-m');
    while (true) {
        try {
            $startDateTime = new DateTime($startDate);
            $startDateTime->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));
            $startDate = $startDateTime->format('Y-m-d');
            $endTime = $startDateTime->format('Y-m-t');
            echo $startDate . ' => ' . $endTime . PHP_EOL;
            if ($startDateTime->format('Y-m') == $endDate) {
                break;
            }
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            var_dump($exception->getMessage());
            break;
        }
    }
```

After testing many solutions, this works best for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one liner that may be of interest.'Y-m-j' is the date format for the output and the second string is the date of interest with an offset string:

```
echo date('Y-m-j', strtotime('2009-12-23 last day of this month'));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function first_last_day($string, $first_last, $format) {
    $result = strtotime($string);
    $year = date('Y',$result);
    $month = date('m',$result);
    $result = strtotime("{$year}-{$month}-01");
    if ($first_last == 'last'){$result = strtotime('-1 second', strtotime('+1 month', $result)); }
    if ($format == 'unix'){return $result; }
    if ($format == 'standard'){return date('Y-m-d', $result); }
}
```

http://zkinformer.com/?p=134

Answer (score -1):

I needed the last day of the next month, maybe someone will need it:

```
echo date("Y-m-t", strtotime("next month")); //is 2020-08-13, return 2020-09-30
```

Answer (score -2):

This a much more elegant way to get the end of the month:

```
  $thedate = Date('m/d/Y'); 
  $lastDayOfMOnth = date('d', mktime(0,0,0, date('m', strtotime($thedate))+1, 0, date('Y', strtotime($thedate))));
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use "`t`" in date function to get the number of day in a particular month.

The code will be something like this:

```
function lastDateOfMonth($Month, $Year=-1) {
    if ($Year < 0) $Year = 0+date("Y");
    $aMonth         = mktime(0, 0, 0, $Month, 1, $Year);
    $NumOfDay       = 0+date("t", $aMonth);
    $LastDayOfMonth = mktime(0, 0, 0, $Month, $NumOfDay, $Year);
    return $LastDayOfMonth;
}

for($Month = 1; $Month <= 12; $Month++)
    echo date("Y-n-j", lastDateOfMonth($Month))."\n";
```

The code is self-explained. So hope it helps.