# Time stamp and adding 1 year and last day in month

Tags: php, timestamp

I have timestamp in DB like: 1268085720, it's 2010-03-08 23:00, so it's today.

How can I add one year, and to be the last day in the same month, and need to convert it like: YYYY-MM-DD HH: MM?

For given example I need 2011-03-31 23:59.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modification of [How to find the last day of the month from date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686724/php-last-day-of-the-month)

```
echo date("Y-m-t 23:59:59", strtotime("+1 year", 1268085720));
// -> 2011-03-31 23:59:59
```

The `t` format gives the number of days in the given month (28 through 31). If you want the real hours and minutes, use `Y-m-t H:i:s` instead of the hardcoded time.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mktime();`

```
$time=1268085720;
$nextyear=mktime(date('h', $time), date('i', $time), date('s', $time), date('m', $time), date('t', $time), date('Y', $time)+1);
```

Comment: This gives 2015-09-01 on my computer when run through date(Y-m-d)

Comment: Oups! I forgot to include the current day... xD --Edited.

Comment: Now it returns 2011-03-08. Still not what the OP was looking for. Use `date('t', $time)` instead of `date('d', $time)`

Answer (score 0):

```
//$result contain the timestamp
$lastday=strtotime('+1 year', $result);
echo date('Y-m-t H:i',$lastday);
```

here :)

Comment: "last day" is "yesterday" in strotime whereas I think the OP was last day of month