# DateTime "first day of last month" not returning the first day

Tags: php, datetime, datediff

I looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9735891/404623) already, and it's quite close to what I have.

Here is my PHP code:

```
$start = new DateTime('0:00 first day of previous month', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
/*
if (isset($_GET['year']) && isset($_GET['month']) && checkdate($_GET['month'], 1, $_GET['year'])) {
    $start = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $_GET['year'] . '-' . $_GET['month'] . '-1');
}*/
$middle = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', strtotime('first day of last month', $start->format('U')));
$middle->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$end = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', strtotime('first day of 2 months ago', $start->format('U')));
$end->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

var_dump($start);
var_dump($middle);
var_dump($end);
```

Today is August 27th, so I would expect July 1, June 1, and May 1. Here's what the actual output is:

```
object(DateTime)[1]
  public 'date' => string '2013-07-01 00:00:00' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)

object(DateTime)[2]
  public 'date' => string '2013-05-02 00:00:00' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)

object(DateTime)[3]
  public 'date' => string '2013-04-02 00:00:00' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
```

Why is it returning the second day of the months for me?

I've also tried it without the `new DateTimeZone('GMT')` as the second parameter of the constructor for the initial `DateTime` but it still gives me the same result, just with different times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### this part irrelevant - question was edited

Because of the timezone difference. $start is calculated in the 'Rainy River timezone', while $middle and $end are in UTC time.
The 'Rainy River timezone has a [-06:00 hour offset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Rainy_River) from UTC (exactly the difference in hours between the first with the second and third results).

#### update 1 - solution

It seems the problem lies somewhere around strtotime. For some reason it yields a result with an offset of one day (further explanation needed). A simple solution, is to subtract one second from that date and it will produce the correct result.

```
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
$start = new DateTime('0:00 first day of previous month', $timezone );
$middle = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', strtotime('first day of last month',($start  ->format('U'))-1),$timezone);
echo $middle->format('Y-m-d')."\n";
```

Result:

```
2013-05-01
```

#### update 2 - reason for problem

Eventually I find out that the problem originates from the instantiation of the fisrt date object. Here is an illustration.

This will give a correct result:

```
$original = new DateTime('2013-05-01');
echo $original->format('Y-m-d')."\n";

$previous= DateTime::createFromFormat('U', strtotime('first day of last month',($original->format('U'))),new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo $previous->format('Y-m-d')."\n";
```

Result (OK):

```
2013-05-01
2013-04-01   <--- OK
```

However, this will not (only first line different, as in the original code):

```
$original = new DateTime('0:00 first day of previous month', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo $original->format('Y-m-d')."\n";

$previous= DateTime::createFromFormat('U', strtotime('first day of last month',($original->format('U'))),new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo $previous->format('Y-m-d')."\n";
```

Result:

```
 2013-07-01
 2013-05-02  <--- BAD
```

Comment: I thought that was the problem but I also tried setting all of the times to UTC... see edited post.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 is there a reason you are instantiating the dates differently? Why not $start= new DateTime("first day of previous month");
$middle = new DateTime("first day of last month");
$end = new DateTime("first day of 2 months ago");

Comment: Because as you can see in my commented code, `$start` might be passed through `$_GET` (specifically dropdown boxes), so the `$middle` and `$end` need to be relative to `$start`.

Comment: +1 for the explanation... gotta learn something new every day! :)

Comment: That's why we're here! :) I would still appreciate an input by a person more experienced in php on how/why the date objects behave like this. It seems they are creating some references, but nothing in the documentation or other online discussions...

Answer (score 4):

After reading [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602405/php-datetimemodify-adding-and-subtracting-months), I had a better idea:

```
$start = new DateTime('0:00 first day of previous month');
/*
if (isset($_GET['year']) && isset($_GET['month']) && checkdate($_GET['month'], 1, $_GET['year'])) {
    $start = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $_GET['year'] . '-' . $_GET['month'] . '-1');
}*/
$middle = clone $start;
$middle->modify('first day of last month');
$end = clone $start;
$end->modify('first day of 2 months ago');

var_dump($start);
var_dump($middle);
var_dump($end);
```

Output:

```
object(DateTime)[1]
  public 'date' => string '2013-07-01 00:00:00' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'America/Rainy_River' (length=19)

object(DateTime)[2]
  public 'date' => string '2013-06-01 00:00:00' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'America/Rainy_River' (length=19)

object(DateTime)[3]
  public 'date' => string '2013-05-01 00:00:00' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'America/Rainy_River' (length=19)
```

Also, I realize that a [`DateTimeImmutable`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php) would be a better choice for the `$start` instance (so that I don't have to clone the other two), but I don't have access to PHP 5.5 yet.

Comment: This is a much cleaner way, thumbs up. However - part of original question was why that particular piece of code didn't work correctly, on which I tried to elaborate.

Comment: Yeah, so for DateTimeImmutable just change the DateTime > DateTimeImmutable, and then you can do: $middle = $start->modify etcetc.