# php querystring to return startdate and enddate of curent month by Default in url

Tags: php

I have a stored procedure with two parameters @startdate and @enddate

And I have a URL as below

'http://localhost/filename.php?startdate='01-08-2012'&enddate='31-08-2012'

As it stands, every month I have to change this manually to get startdate and enddate of the present month. For e.g. for September, i will have to change '01-09-2012' '31-09-2012'

I'm looking for php code or function which will  take automatically first day of every month as startdate and last day of the the month as enddate in the url?

Comment: you don't need to single-quote the date in your query string. And what have you tried ?

Comment: Possible dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680501/how-can-i-find-the-first-and-last-date-in-a-month-using-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and last day of the previous month:

```
$current_year = date('Y');
$current_month = date('m');
$lastdateofmonth = date('t', $current_month);
$startdate = "01-$current_month-$current_year";
$enddate = "$lastdateofmonth-$current_month-$current_year";
```

Comment: Thanks...What I shall write in url? [localhost/filename.php?startdate='01-08-2012'&enddate='31-08-2012]

Comment: with this code you don't need to pass anything in the URL. try it.

Comment: shall i replace your text "first day" and "second day" with text startdate and enddate because my parameters are startdate and enddate. I copied and pasted entire your code but it just prints the date.

Comment: I changed the code, now it'll set the parameters like you need (startdate, enddate). It would be easier if you showed me your code and what would you expect as an output.

Comment: Now it worked. Many Thanks..As I'm new to coding..i'm not able to understand easily..i simply didn't know to add $startdate and $enddate. After you changed it for me, it worked.

Answer (score 4):

First day:

```
date('Y-m-01'); //current year and month
```

Last day:

```
date("Y-m-t"); //current year and month and t means the last day of this month
```

Change the formatting for your needs.