# How to get last day of the month using php

Tags: php

How to get last day of the month using php ?

```
<?php
     echo date('?-?-?');
?>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<?php
$day=new DateTime('last day of this month'); 
echo $day->format('M jS');
?>
```

Answer (score 9):

The [date function documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) says that `t` represents number of days in current month:

```
$day = date( 't-m-Y' );
```

Comment: I love this method ;) super simple!

Answer (score 8):

try this

```
$day=date('Y-m-t'); // gives last day of current month
```

**OR**

```
$d = new DateTime( '2013-05-03' ); 
echo $d->format( 'Y-m-t' );
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$last_day = date('t-m-Y');
```

where `t` means the last date of the current month.

[PHP: date - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

[How can I find the first and last date in a month using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680501/how-can-i-find-the-first-and-last-date-in-a-month-using-php)

Answer (score 1):

Using the function `date` you would do

```
$day = date("t");
```

Please read the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$date = new DateTime();
$lastDayOfMonth = $date->modify(
  sprintf('+%d days', $date->format('t') - $date->format('j'))
);
```