# How to get last day of current month?

Tags: php

I want to apply a competition event. Winner will be announce at last day of current month. i.e: current month is November. I want to display a message like: `Final declaration will be announced at 30th November 10:00:00 pm`

I want to get `30th November 10:00:00 pm` from php function. Any idea?

Comment: Use `t` in the date function, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1686742/3112492

Comment: [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351396/how-to-get-last-day-of-the-month-using-php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This produces the same result:

```
echo date('t F 10:00:00') . "pm";
```

Answer (score 1):

`date` returns a formatted date string and accepts the format specifier as the first argument, with an optional second argument as the timestamp. So `date` alone doesn't get you want you want unless you first calculate the last day of the current month as a Unix timestamp and provide it to `date`.

You can do this with `strtotime`, which accepts [relative date/times](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) in string form and translates them back to Unix timestamps in integer form.

```
echo date('jS F g:i:s a', strtotime('last day of this month'));
// should give you something like 30th November 1:02:02 pm
```