# How to get month start and end date from 2 date range in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, date

I have 2 date range

1) 10 Jan to 25 Dec 2017

2) 25 Jan to 10 Dec 2017

now here i want an array that have start-date and end-date of every month.
with this condition

if first month have >15 days then i want array like this (for 10 Jan to 25 Dec 2017 date range)

```
array (
array (
'start_date' => '01/10/2017',
'end_date' => '01/31/2017',
'total_days'=>'21'),
array (
'start_date' => '02/01/2017',
'end_date' => '02/28/2017',
'total_days'=>'28'),
......
.......
array (
'start_date' => '12/01/2017',
'end_date' => '12/25/2017',
'total_days'=>'25'),
)
```

2nd if first month have <15 days then first month start-date + next month's end-date then next month's start + end-date and so on if first month have less then 15 days.

for 25 Jan to 10 Dec 2017 date rang

```
array (
array (
'start_date' => '01/10/2017',
'end_date' => '02/28/2017',
'total_days'=>'38'),
array (
'start_date' => '03/01/2017',
'end_date' => '03/31/2017',
'total_days'=>'31'),
......
.......
array (
'start_date' => '12/01/2017',
'end_date' => '12/10/2017',
'total_days'=>'10'),
)
```

Thanks

Comment: I think this can help you to figure out about the first and last date of a month and rest you check by giving some conditions.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680501/how-can-i-find-the-first-and-last-date-in-a-month-using-php. Show us what you have tried till now.