# How to get first and last date of the month from a given numeric month PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date, php-carbon

I want to get the first date and last date of the month if given I have a numeric number of the month.

For example January  = 01, October = 10, November = 11

So if I pass 10 as parameter I should get the first and last date of October.

I tried to implement it using [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/). But I gives me different result.

Here is the code. The result is is next to it.

```
$dt =  Carbon::create(10);
echo $dt->startOfMonth(); // 0010-10-01 00:00:00
echo $dt->endOfMonth(); // 0010-10-31 00:00:00
```

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680501/how-can-i-find-the-first-and-last-date-in-a-month-using-php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first day of any month is the first.

use [createFromFormat](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

```
$dt = Carbon::createFromFormat('m', 10);
echo $dt->endOfMonth();
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with this line:

```
Carbon::create(10);
```

Carbon's `create` method takes the following list of parameters:

```
$year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute, $second, $tz
```

And you're only providing the first one. So you end up with an object representing today's date, but in the year **10**.

If you want to only provide the `month` argument, you should use:

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('m', 10);
```

Be aware that this will default to the current year, so results for February won't always be consistent.