# Get first and last date of current month in PHP

Tags: php, date

How can I get the `first` and `last` date of the current month within PHP? I need this for a code which accepts a date range which has this format here:

```
array( 'date_paid' => $date_min . '...' . $date_max );
```

I know that this is a small function but I'm not sure how to do this. I would appreciate a little help. Thanks guys!

Comment: ASC and DESC ??? get ist and last day of the month?

Comment: First and last day of the current month, right

Comment: I don't understand the question. You want to get the more recent date ?

Comment: You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680501/how-can-i-find-the-first-and-last-date-in-a-month-using-php) SO question I think

Comment: @executable Update my question. I wrote it not clear, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You can get [relative formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) of date to get the first and last days of the current month

```
$firstDay = new DateTime('first day of this month');
$lastDay  = new DateTime('last day of this month');

$result = array(
    'date_paid' => $firstDay->format('Y-m-d') . '...' . $lastDay->format('Y-m-d') 
);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$firstDay = mktime(0,0,0, $month, 1, $year);
$lastDay = mktime(0,0,0, $month + 1, 0, $year);
```

$lastDay has 0 as the day which makes it the last day of the last month and thus `$month + 1`