# Get the last day of the month?

Tags: php, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP last day of the month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686724/php-last-day-of-the-month)

Is there any function like `$date->getMonthDays()` or `$date->getLastDayOfMonth()` in PHP to get the number of days in a given month (or the last day number)?

```
$start = new DateTime('2012-02-01');
$end   = clone $start;

// Interval = last day of the month minus current day in $start
$interval = $start->getLastDayOfMonth() - intval($start->format('j'));
$end->add(new DateInterval('P' . $interval . 'D'));
```

EDIT: thanks, **voted to close**, it's a duplicate, sorry for asking...

Comment: I don't know PHP, but generally, you can get last day by get first day of next month then -1

Comment: `(DateTimeObj)->format('t');` would give you the number of days in that month.

Comment: @EricYin that is a good idea, i'll give it a try if there is no native PHP function, thanks a lot.

Comment: With `DateTime` you can do something like this: `(new DateTime('2012-02-01'))->modify('last day of')`.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The php date function gives you the number of days in the month with 't'

```
date("t");
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 29):

It's simple to get last month date

```
echo date("Y-m-t", strtotime("-1 month") ) ;
echo date("Y-m-1", strtotime("-1 month") ) ;
```

at March 3 returns

```
2011-02-28
2011-02-1
```

Answer (score 6):

`t` gives you the total number of days in the current month. `j` gives you the current day of the month.

Using `modify` and some subtraction from `format`-ing the datetime, you can get to the end of the month.

```
$date = new DateTime();
$lastDayOfMonth = $date->modify(
  sprintf('+%d days', $date->format('t') - $date->format('j'))
);
```