# PHP add date to month end

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP last day of the month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686724/php-last-day-of-the-month)

I have to set an expiry date to my application.

First user have to select a duration of listing, for eg its 1 year and today is 25-Nov-2012

Then we have to add this 1 year to current date and automatically set expiry date as its month end. ie expiry date will be **30-Nov-2013**

If current date is 04-Oct-2012 and select 1 year duration, then expiry date is 31-Oct-2012.

I success in add one/two/ whatever years to the current date, but how to find out its month end ?

Comment: Do you know timestamp? You should rather use timestamp to save and calculate the delta between values (current and the value saved in DB) ;-)

Comment: Please see http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912780/get-the-last-day-of-the-month - this might help

Comment: in function date, parameter "t" return number of days in the given month http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
echo date("Y-m-t", strtotime("+1 year"));
```

[See the DOCs for `strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

And [using `t` for the date function to get the last day of the month](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: This does not return the last day of the month for the return date

Comment: Ta, just beat you to it ;-)

Comment: @Alex no you did not. look at the timestamp of my comment vs your post :-P

Comment: I swear, it said 38 seconds for yours and a couple for mine. It lies!

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following should work for you:

```
echo date("Y-m-t", strtotime("+1 year"));
```

Comment: :-P Yep. sorry for the error before.

Answer (score -1):

try this code:

```
echo date(date('t',strtotime($date)) . '-M-Y', strtotime($date . ' +1 year'));
```