# Grab last day of last month in PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP last day of the month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686724/php-last-day-of-the-month)

In PHP, I am trying to get the last day of last month.
For example, today is December 11 2012. So the date I am then trying to grab is November 30th.

This is what I am currently trying to do:

```
        //this grabs the last daye of this month
        $current_month = date('Y-m-t',strtotime('today'));

        //this should grab November 30th.
        $last_month = date("F, Y",strtotime($current_month." -1 month ")
```

Instead of it grabbing November 30th, it is grabbing December 1st. Is seems like "-1 month" simply subtracts 30 days.

How do I properly grab the last day of last month?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call [mktime()](http://php.net/mktime) with current month/year and `0` as day:

```
$last_day_of_last_month = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n'), 0, date('Y'));
```

It's documented:

> **day** [...] Values less than 1 (including negative values) reference the days in the previous month, so 0 is the last day of the previous
>   month, -1 is the day before that, etc. Values greater than the number
>   of days in the relevant month reference the appropriate day in the
>   following month(s).

Answer (score 5):

```
$datetime = new DateTime('last day of this month');
echo $datetime->format('F jS');
```

or

```
$datetime = new DateTime();
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-t');
```

The first one allows you to format the output anyway you want to. If you want to use a month that is not the current month you can pass the DateTime constructor a [valid date format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) and then the code will do the rest.

Comment: I get `Failed to parse time string` on PHP/5.4.5 Windows. Perhaps it requires the time libraries bundled in Linux :-?

Comment: I'm getting a server error and I am running the newest version of php

Comment: I modified my answer to use an alternative method that may work better for everybody

Answer (score 4):

cal_days_in_month() is what you want. The last day is the same as the total number of days.

```
cal_days_in_month (int $calendar,int $month,int $year)
```

$calendar is typically CAL_GREGORIAN

Send the $month - 1 to the function for the result you want.