# Last day of each month within a date range in php

Tags: php

How to get last day of each month within a date range in PHP?

Input:

> $startdate = '2013-01-15'
>   $enddate = '2013-03-15'

The output that I want is:

> **2013-01-31**   *End date of January*
>   **2013-02-28**    *End date of February*
>   **2013-03-15**    *End date of March is '2013-03-31' but the end date is '2013-03-15' .

So I want `2013-03-15`.

How can I do that?

Comment: have you tried anything...?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686724/php-last-day-of-the-month

Comment: you can get very good example [here](http://www.dbforums.com/php/1617949-months-between-two-dates.html). Not exactly what you want but a good start.

Comment: @bmewsing I saw that post.But my requirement is another.

Comment: @bmewsing If my date range is January 15 to march 15,then i want the last date of march as march 15, last date of January as January 31 and last date of February as February 28

Comment: check my answer. It may help you. Its giving exact results that you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function get_months($date1, $date2) {

    $time1 = strtotime($date1);
    $time2 = strtotime($date2);

    $my = date('mY', $time2);
    $months = array(date('Y-m-t', $time1));
    $f = '';

    while($time1 < $time2) {
        $time1 = strtotime((date('Y-m-d', $time1).' +15days'));

        if(date('F', $time1) != $f) {
            $f = date('F', $time1);

            if(date('mY', $time1) != $my && ($time1 < $time2))
                $months[] = date('Y-m-t', $time1);
        }

    }

    $months[] = date('Y-m-d', $time2);
    return $months;
}

$myDates = get_months('2005-01-20', '2005-11-25');
```

$myDates will have the output you want. It will work even if years are different. Logic is from this [URL](http://www.dbforums.com/php/1617949-months-between-two-dates.html)

Comment: You could have just as easily posted the link where you got the code from http://www.dbforums.com/php/1617949-months-between-two-dates.html

Comment: @Pankrates: With all due respect, i would like to inform you that i have already posted the link above in comment section. I guess, you have not observed it in hurry to answer this question. Moreover, the example shown at the URL that you have mentioned in your comment is not exactly what Nandu neaded. So, i have modified it. And i have already mentioned in my answer that logic is from that URL. So, Please start observing things...

Comment: You are right, I did notice the link in the original comment but I did not see it was posted by the same user. My apologies

Answer (score 4):

In the future, try to write the code yourself. If you are stuck with a specific part you can request help. Exception for this one time:

```
<?php

$startdate  = new DateTime('2013-01-15'); 
$enddate    = new DateTime('2013-04-15');

$year = $startdate->format('Y');

$start_month    = (int)$startdate->format('m');
$end_month      = (int)$enddate->format('m');

for ( $i=$start_month; $i<$end_month; $i++) {
    $date = new DateTime($year.'-'.$i);
    echo $date->format('Y-m-t').' End date of '.$date->format('F');
}

echo $enddate->format('Y-m-d');
```

Will output:

```
2013-01-31 End date of January
2013-02-28 End date of February
2013-03-31 End date of March
2013-04-15
```

Note that this does not work if the start and end dates have a different year. I have left this as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

I'm little changed the function:

```
function get_months($date1, $date2) {

    $time1 = strtotime($date1);
    $time2 = strtotime($date2);

    $my = date('mY', $time2);

    $f = '';

    while($time1 < $time2) {
        $time1 = strtotime((date('Y-m-d', $time1).' +15days'));

        if(date('F', $time1) != $f) {
            $f = date('F', $time1);

            if(date('mY', $time1) != $my && ($time1 < $time2))
                $months[] = array(date('Y-m-01', $time1),date('Y-m-t', $time1));
        }

    }

    $months[] = array(date('Y-m-01', $time2),date('Y-m-d', $time2));
    return $months;
}
```