# Strange behaviour with numbers that have a leading zero

Tags: php, numbers, integer, octal

I have some PHP code with some integers and all works fine, except when I have `08` or `0X` as integer. It all works fine when I put them in quote.

Example numbers:

```
2      //Works fine
08     //Doesn't work
012    //Doesn't work
"08"   //Works fine again
"012"  //Works fine again
```

Can anyone tell me the reason behind it?

Comment: 0 in front of a number is considered as Octal number by PHP.

Comment: Suggest you read about how to get the number of days in a month, and how to use loops, as well as how to use integers

Comment: I concur. Very inefficient code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686724/php-last-day-of-the-month

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you simply write 08 and 09 (without quotes) or any other numeric with a leading 0, PHP believes you're writing an octal value, and 08 and 09 are invalid octal numbers.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

> **Syntax**
>
> Integers can be specified in decimal (base 10), hexadecimal (base 16),
> octal (base 8) or binary (base 2) notation, optionally preceded by a
> sign (- or +).
>
> Binary integer literals are available since PHP 5.4.0.
>
> To use **octal notation**, precede the number with a **0** (zero). To use
> **hexadecimal notation** precede the number with **0x**. To use **binary
> notation** precede the number with **0b**.
>
> [...]
>
> **Warning:**
> Prior to PHP 7, if an invalid digit was given in an octal integer (i.e. 8 or 9), the rest of the number was ignored. Since PHP 7, a parse error is emitted.