# Get first and last day from last month

Tags: php, date

I have this:

```
$today=date('Y-m-d');
// echo "2013-11-12";
```

I want to get the last month range like this:

```
$startLastMonth = "2013-10-01";
$endLastMonth   = "2013-10-31";
```

I try that but it's does not meet my desire as I need to put 42:

```
$startLastMonth = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("Y"), date("m"),   date("d")-42);
```

Is there another way ?

Thanks

Comment: It is totally not clear what you want.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686724/php-last-day-of-the-month

Comment: @wumm OP wants first and last day from last month and not for current month.

Comment: @Marcell Fülöp: Not clear. Haha. Try to read it again. You are the only one who not understand it as others gave me an advice.

Comment: -1 Please use the SO site search first, there are at least two identical duplicates…

Comment: Just use `Y-m-t` format to get last date of the month, and close this question for duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code below should work

```
$startLastMonth = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m") - 1, 1, date("Y"));
$endLastMonth = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), 0, date("Y"));
```

What you're doing is telling PHP that a) you want the 1st day of the previous month (`date("m") - 1`), and b) telling PHP you want the 0th day of the *current* month, which, according to mktime documentation, becomes the last day of the previous month. Documentation can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

If you want to format the output as in your  you can do

```
$startOutput = date("Y-m-d", $startLastMonth);
$endOutput = date("Y-m-d", $endLastMonth);
```

Comment: The output (`2013-10-01` and `2013-10-31`) will be in the `$startOutput` and `$endOutput` variables.

Comment: I've for $startOutput: 2168-09-10...

Comment: Oops, got the wrong order for the arguments! It should work now! :)

Answer (score 3):

Just use the relative date/time formats that are provided by PHP:

```
var_dump( new DateTime( 'first day of last month' ) );
var_dump( new DateTime( 'last day of last month' ) );
```

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

Answer (score 0):

Here's a handy little function that will do what you want. You will get back an array containing the first and last days of the previous month to the date supplied:-

```
function getLastMonth(DateTime $date)
{
    //avoid side affects
    $date = clone $date;
    $date->modify('first day of last month');
    return array(
        $date->format('Y-m-d'),
        $date->format('Y-m-t'),
    );
}

var_dump(getLastMonth(new \DateTime()));
```

Output:-

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string '2013-10-01' (length=10)
  1 => string '2013-10-31' (length=10)
```

In PHP > 5.3 you can do this:-

```
list($start, $end) = getLastMonth(new \DateTime());
var_dump($start, $end);
```

Output:-

```
string '2013-10-01' (length=10)
string '2013-10-31' (length=10)
```

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/8v8C4).

Comment: Thanks but why make it hard for nothing? date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")+1, 1, date("Y"))) made the job.

Comment: Yes, but mktime will not allow for leap years and DST changes. This will.

Comment: Are you sure mktime won't work like that?

Comment: Yes, reasonably sure, although I'm always prepared to be proved wrong.