# Getting the day before at end of month

Tags: php

Right now if you where to use `strtotime('1 month')` on January 31st you would get march 1st but I wondering if there is a simple way that if I where to run that same script on the same day instead of getting march 1st I could get February 28. Is this possible? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT:

Sorry I think I did not explain this properly, I want to be able to always get 30 days except for months where that day dont exists. So for instance if it is January 31st I want to be able to get February 28th but if it was January 10 I want February 10.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP last day of the month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686724/php-last-day-of-the-month)

Comment: Please see my edit its slightly more complicated then just the end of the month

Comment: just add 30 to your date? why do you need strtotime for that? or `strtotime(+30 day)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a more verbose text:

```
$date = new DateTime('last day of next month');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
// => 2014-10-31
```

**EDIT:**

To answer your updated question, you can start with `next month` and compare it to `last day of next month`. If `next month` is larger than `last day of next month`, use `last day of next month` instead:

```
$date = new DateTime('next month');
if ($date > ($end = new DateTime('last day of next month'))) {
  $date = $end;
}
```

Comment: `if ($date > ($end = new DateTime('last day of next month')))` - *Interesting*.