# PHP add month to date on a date with day of month 31

Tags: php, date, datetime, strtotime

I'm using code that works fine on all dates, except 2015-05-31.
The code brings me the first day of next month. 
it works on every date, even if day of month is 31.

```
$time = strtotime('2015-07-31');
$final = date("Y-m-1", strtotime("+1 month", $time));
echo $final;
```

output will be --> 2015-08-1.

For some reason on the date 2015-05-31 it returns 2015-07-1 instead of 2015-06-01

```
$time = strtotime('2015-05-31');
$final = date("Y-m-1", strtotime("+1 month", $time));
echo $final;
```

Its probably because 6-2014 has 30 days, and 8-2014 has 31 days, so +1 month adds 30 days and not a "month".

How could i get correctly the first day of next month on every date?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP last day of the month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686724/php-last-day-of-the-month)

Comment: Its a different question.

Comment: The question I linked to tells you how to get the "last day of the current month" and in your question you asked for the "first day of next month".

Comment: I know, but the answer there is not solving the problem in this question.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6: created fiddle, can you please try to solve using your link http://ideone.com/9S0Xae

Comment: @SureshKamrushi I should probably have linked to the exact answer that I was referring to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18329649/404623

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this should work -

```
$time = strtotime("2015-05-31");
echo $final = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("first day of next month", $time));
```

Comment: It does not understand to string, the return is "1969-12-31". May be depends on php version. Yes, >=5.3

Answer (score -1):

You can try like this:

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2000-12-31');
$interval = new DateInterval('P1M');

$date->add($interval);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";

$date->add($interval);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
?>
```

Output:

```
2001-01-31
2001-03-03
```

For more information :https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Comment: If you run your code on 2015-05-31 the output will be "2015-07-01 2015-08-01". same problem.