# PHP - Get number of days from start-end dates

Tags: php, date

**Case One:**

```
$start_date = 01-Mar-15
$end_date = 31-Apr-15
```

Fetch number of days for start-end date. Here it will be `31 days` for both the dates.

**Case One:**

```
$start_date = 16-Mar-15
$end_date = 15-Apr-15
```

Here it will not be the same so fetch number of days for `start_date` i.e. `30 days`.

How can I execute below condition based on above use-cases:

```
if($start_date_month_days == $end_date_month_days){
//do something with 31 dates
}else{
//do something with number of days for $start_date month
}
```

P.S. : I am not looking for number of days between two dates. But to fetch the number of days for specific `start-end` dates. That dates cold be in same/different months

Comment: Please be more clear. Are you looking for how many days are in between those two dates?

Comment: Are you okay with using PHP's built-in [DateTime](https://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) or the [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) extension?

Comment: @treegarden, I am not looking for number of days between two dates. Just to fetch the number of days for specific `start-end` dates. That dates cold be in same/different months

Comment: There are tons of similar questions to this one asked in SO already, so it's worth doing a search. You'll find the PHP's built in `DateInterval` useful: http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php  Edit: I wasn't the downvoter btw

Comment: *"fetch the number of days for specific start-end dates"* – I have no idea what that means. I don't see how March 1st, April 31st results in 31 days.

Comment: That means if the start-end dates are, say for, month of March then it should return 31 days else if they are for apr, it should return 30 days

Comment: possible duplicate of [finding-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040560/finding-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates)

Comment: Sooooooo... you just want to figure out how many days there are in a particular month...?

Comment: Yes, but that will be based on months for start-end dates. Month could vary. Thus I explained with a user-case in my question

Comment: Sooooooo... You figure out how many days there are in your start date's month and then how many days there are in your end date's month and then you do something with it...?

Comment: Yes you are correct.

Comment: And existing questions like this didn't help...?! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686724/how-to-find-the-last-day-of-the-month-from-date

Answer (score -1):

```
  $start_date = "01-Mar-15";
    $end_date = "31-Apr-15";

    $date1 = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d",strtotime($start_date)));
    $date2 = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d",strtotime($end_date)));
    $interval = $date1->diff($date2);

    echo "".$interval->d." days";

if($interval->d=="31"){
//do something
}
else{
}
```

Try this code

Comment: Generally this is going in the right direction, but there's a ton wrong with this code.

Comment: The way you're instantiating `DateTime` is still broken.