# php get last day of given month

Tags: php, date, datetime

I want to output of last and first date of a given month of current year. I am using this code but not works

```
$month='02';
$first_day_this_month = date('Y-'.$month.'-01'); // hard-coded '01' for first day
$last_day_this_month  = date('Y-'.$month.'-t');

echo $first_day_this_month;print'<->';echo $last_day_this_month;
```

my output shows

```
2015-02-01<->2015-02-31
```

But it will be `2015-02-01<->2015-02-28`

Comment: Get the timestamp with: `strototime("last day of February 2015");` - [Example](http://www.tehplayground.com/#j1rFj2F5T).

Comment: Mixing `echo` and `print`?  For shame!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have had this problem with PHP before, try the following way:

```
$dateToTest = "2015-02-01";
$lastday = date('t',strtotime($dateToTest));
```

Comment: gg... strtotime will break after 2038?

Comment: 21 years time.. I doubt the Unix timestamp as we know it will exist then.

But if this "Y2K" issue still scares you then for MySQL, store dates as DATETIME rather than TIMESTAMP.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/2012620/1618363

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. See other question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686724/how-to-find-the-last-day-of-the-month-from-date

Answer (score 11):

You can use [DateTime methods](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php):

```
$month = '02';

$date = new DateTime(date('Y').'-'.$month.'-01');
$date->modify('last day of this month');
$last_day_this_month = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 6):

there are many ways to do that, i give you two answers\ideas:

1- Try to use `strtotime` PHP function (http://php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php)

Something like `date("Y-m-d", strtotime("last day of this month"));` or first day... or any month.

2- Other way you can use that:

First day:

```
date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, *YOUR MONTH PARAM*,1 ,date("Y")));
```

Last day:

```
date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, *YOUR MONTH PARAM*+1,0,date("Y")));
```

Read about **mktime** function here:

http://php.net/manual/es/function.mktime.php

Good luck!

Comment: Remember do not hard-coded if you can!

Answer (score 4):

You can with DateTime class.

```
    $month='02';
    $first_day_this_month = date('Y-'.$month.'-01');

    $firstDayThisMonth = new \DateTime($first_day_this_month);

    $lastDayThisMonth = new \DateTime($firstDayThisMonth->format('Y-m-t'));
    $lastDayThisMonth->setTime(23, 59, 59);

    echo $firstDayThisMonth->format("Y-m-d");
    echo "<->";
    echo $lastDayThisMonth->format("Y-m-d");
```