# Get last day of month using existing date

Tags: php, datetime

I'm currently using `DateTime` objects to perform some calculations involving dates. For this instance, I'm trying to get the last day of the month using a pre-existing date.  I tried the following code and wound up with an incorrect value for `$endDate`, that being `1970-1-1`.

```
$startDate = new DateTime(date("Y-m-1"));
$endDate = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("last day of month", $startDate->format("Y-m-d"))));

echo "The start date should be 2016-1-1: " . $startDate->format("Y-m-d") . "<br />";
echo "The end date should be 2016-1-31: " . $endDate->format("Y-m-d") . "<br />";
```

How can I get it working correctly so that `$endDate` comes out to the desired result?  I don't want it to be this month specifically; it should work for any date string I supply via `$startDate`.

Comment: Do you get the last day in a month or the name of the last day in a month? You can use `cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year)`. The last day is the number of days too

Comment: I just tried this and I'm still getting the same results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the last day of the month from date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686724/how-to-find-the-last-day-of-the-month-from-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it using some of the suggestions below.

```
$startDate = new DateTime(date("2012-4-1"));
$endDate = new DateTime(date("Y-m-t", strtotime($startDate->format("Y-m-d"))));

echo "The start date should be 2012-4-1: " . $startDate->format("Y-m-d") . "<br />";
echo "The end date should be 2012-4-30: " . $endDate->format("Y-m-d") . "<br />";
```

I've verified that this works.

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime` expects the second parameter to be a timestamp. Try this instead:

```
$endDate = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("last day of month", $startDate->getTimestamp())));
```

Comment: This failed as well.  I'm still getting the 1970 date.

Answer (score 0):

Use char "t" in your datetime as it is the number of days in the given month

```
$endDate = new DateTime(date("Y-m-t"));
```

Comment: If anything, it's now showing the correct DAY, but it's still the wrong year of 1970.

Comment: And the $startDate is showing correct year? Because I've just tried this on my machine and it results in correct result

Answer (score 0):

This page may have the answer you seek:
[How to find the last day of the month from date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686724/how-to-find-the-last-day-of-the-month-from-date)

Applied to your code:

```
$startDate = new DateTime(date("Y-m-1"));
$endDate = new DateTime(date("Y-m-t", $startDate->getTimestamp()));

echo "The start date should be 2016-1-1: " . $startDate->format("Y-m-d") . "<br />";
echo "The end date should be 2016-1-31: " . $endDate->format("Y-m-d") . "<br />";
```

Comment: This is only a partial solution.  The dates are intended to be from last month, so I need to be able to use $startDate to generate $endDate (if $startDate is 2015-3-1, $endDate needs to be 2015-3-31).

Comment: Ah, see updated code in this answer. This generates a proper end of month date for whatever month is specified in $startDate. If you wanted to specify "last month", you could alter $startDate to: `$startDate = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("first day of previous month")));`

Comment: ...and I edited one more time to use DateTime's getTimestamp() instead of converting from a DateTime to a string to a timestamp...

Comment: You made a small error.  Where you assign $endDate, you put `Y-m-1` when it should be `Y-m-d`.

Comment: Actually, should have been Y-m-t (thank you others posting here, I'll check my work next time)