# Date comparison issue using DateTime class in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I created a function to compare dates:

```
public function checkExpiredDate($cardDate) : bool
{
     $currentDate = new DateTime();
     $creditCardDate = new DateTime("{$cardDate->card_expiryYear}-{$cardDate->card_expiryMonth}-*last day from the month*");
     echo $creditCardDate->format('Y-m-d'); exit();
     return $creditCardDate->getTimestamp() < $currentDate->getTimestamp() ?? true;
}
```

I only have the `month` and `year` , not the `day`. I need to compare today's date with that date using only the `month` and `year` and the `DateTime` class . How can I do that ? Is there a way to get the last day from a month and year using the DateTime class? If I could get it someone using `DateTime` , my function should work .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686724/how-to-find-the-last-day-of-the-month-from-date

Comment: Hi, would it be an option to use the date() class instead? Why do you need the last day of the month if you only have the month and the year to compare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set day as the 1st day of the month and then modify to the last

```
$creditCardDate = new DateTime("{$cardDate->card_expiryYear}-{$cardDate->card_expiryMonth}-1");
$creditCardDate->modify('last day of this month');
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely it's easier not to use `DateTime` at all here:

```
return $cardDate->card_expiryYear . $cardDate->card_expiryMonth <= date('Ym');
```

This assumes `$cardDate->card_expiryYear . $cardDate->card_expiryMonth` concatenates to something like `201709`; use some number formatting to achieve this format otherwise:

```
return sprintf('%d%02d', $cardDate->card_expiryYear, $cardDate->card_expiryMonth) <= date('Ym');
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php

```
$creditCardDate->modify('last day of this month');
```