# How to get start date by month number?

Tags: php, php-carbon

I have a number of month in range `1-12`

How to get start and end of date by month number like this:

```
2018-01-01 - 2018-31-01
```

Comment: You may want to look at [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [mktime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php).

Comment: I am not sure, I know current year and number of month, in conclusion I need to get datetime format for insertion to db

Comment: use `t` in format. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686724/how-to-find-the-last-day-of-the-month-from-date

Comment: and start day is always `1` right?  unless you're from other planet

Comment: Read about the [DateFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the last day of the month from date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686724/how-to-find-the-last-day-of-the-month-from-date)

Comment: Read question carefully. I talk about month, not days

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$month = '01';
$start_date = date('Y-'.$month.'-01');
$end_date = date('Y-'.$month.'-t');
```

Comment: I have range from 1 - to 12

Comment: so you want to display all? from 1 to 12?

Comment: No, I have number of month like: 2 I need to get fulldate time like 2018-02-24