# How to get the start date and end date when the year number and month number are known in php

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have the year number (ex: 2018) and the month number (Ex:04). I want to get the starting date and the ending date for that month. like

2018-04-01 and 2018-04-30

Comment: Well, starting date is `YEAR-MONTH-01`, end date is `YEAR-NEXT_MONTH-01 - 1`.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686724/how-to-find-the-last-day-of-the-month-from-date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the last day of the month from date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686724/how-to-find-the-last-day-of-the-month-from-date)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
$year = 2018;
$month = 4;

$date_start = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date($year.'-'.$month).' first day of this month'));
$date_end = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date($year.'-'.$month).'last day of this month'));

echo $date_start . ' and ' . $date_end;
```

Comment: I think this is not what he's searching for. He wants to get the first and last day of a given month

Comment: check the question again... he saying he need like : `2018-04-01 and 2018-04-30`

Comment: Your answer will output 2 times the same thing

Comment: it will echo `2018-04-01 and 2018-04-30`

Comment: Okay you got the point, I didn't know it, just tried and it works

Comment: Guys guys..sorry for the delay @Anfath..your solution works.

Answer (score 0):

```
$months_array = $this->getting_particular_months_dates($start_day_of_year, $end_day_of_year);

                $arra1=array();
                foreach ($months_array as $K => $v)
                {
                    $year=explode( '-',$v['month'])[1];
                    $month=explode( '-',$v['month'])[0];

                    $arra1[]=$this->get_month_dates((int)$year,(int)$month);


                }
                return $arra1;

public function getting_particular_months_dates($year_start_date, $year_end_date)
    {
        $month_array = array();

        $date1 = $year_start_date;
        $date2 = $year_end_date;
        $output = [];
        $time = strtotime($date1);
        $last = date('m-Y', strtotime($date2));
        do {
            $month = date('m-Y', $time);
            $total = date('t', $time);

            $output[] = [
                'month' => $month,
                'total' => $total,
            ];

            $time = strtotime('+1 month', $time);
        } while ($month != $last);

        $month_array = $output;

        return $month_array;
    }

public function get_month_dates($year, $month)
    {
        $date_start = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date($year . '-' . $month) . ' first day of this month'));
        $date_end = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date($year . '-' . $month) . 'last day of this month'));

        $a = array('first_day' => $date_start, 'last_day' => $date_end);

        return $a;
    }
```