# How to count the number of days of a current month in php?

Tags: php, count, days

I have a [fiddle](https://3v4l.org/mf96r) in which I want to calculate the number of days of the current month.

The snippets of code which I have used in the fiddle is:

```
<?php
    $current_month_first_day = new DateTime('first day of this month'); // first day of the current month
    $current_month_last_day  = date('t');  // last day of the current month
    $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
    $period = new DatePeriod($current_month_first_day, $interval, $current_month_last_day - 1);
    print_r($period); // Line A
?>
```

**Line A prints:**

```
DatePeriod Object
(
    [start] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2020-02-01 18:03:30.000268
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => Europe/Amsterdam
        )

    [current] => 
    [end] => 
    [interval] => DateInterval Object
        (
            [y] => 0
            [m] => 0
            [d] => 1
            [h] => 0
            [i] => 0
            [s] => 0
            [f] => 0
            [weekday] => 0
            [weekday_behavior] => 0
            [first_last_day_of] => 0
            [invert] => 0
            [days] => 
            [special_type] => 0
            [special_amount] => 0
            [have_weekday_relative] => 0
            [have_special_relative] => 0
        )

    [recurrences] => 29
    [include_start_date] => 1
)
```

`[recurrences]` prints `29` in the debug above which means there are 29 days in the current month.

**php code:**

```
<!-- YES/NO START -->
<div class="choose-options">
         <h4 style="text-align:center;">Yes/No</h4> 
         <div class="yes-no-option" style="display:inline-grid;">   
    <?php for ($i=0; $i<=29; $i++ ) { ?>   <!-- I have harcoded 29 but it should be coming through php variable --> <!-- Line B --> 
          <select name="house_sitting_date_yes_no[]" class="house-yes-no" style="height:24px; margin-bottom:20px;">
            <option value="nada">Please choose an option</option>
            <option value="yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="no">No</option>
          </select>
    <?php }  ?>  
    </div>
 </div> 
<!-- YES/NO END -->
```

**Problem Statement:**

I wondering what changes I should make in the **php code** at **Line B** so that it loop through **29 times** (**depending on the number of days of the current month. At the moment, I have hardcoded 29 but it should be coming through php variable**). 
The reason why I want to calculate the number of days as I want to run the **for loop 29 times** at **Line B (or 30 times or 31 times)** depending on the number of 
days current month has.

Comment: You do know that php already has that built in, right? You can use `t` on the [date function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), which will also work on a DateTime object.  https://3v4l.org/QT7dK

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686724/how-to-find-the-last-day-of-the-month-from-date

Comment: You could just use `foreach()` over the `$period` value you get from your first script.

Comment: `<?php for ($i=0; $i<=date('t'); $i++ ) {` and throw the rest away

Comment: @RiggsFolly It works, thanks.

Comment: @NigelRen I am wondering if you can let me know in an answer how can we do that through `foreach()` loop over the `$period`.

Comment: @flash was answering when the question was closed. Effectively the question can be rephrased as "*How to iterate over each day including the last day of the current month with DatePeriod*" to reopen it. But you can use https://3v4l.org/ffgBt for an example and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

try this it is give number of days in current month

```
echo cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, date('m', time()), date('Y', time()));
```

OR

echo date('t');