# DateTime modify function skips February

Tags: php, date

When adding a month to with `DateTime::modify` method, the result skips February.

- Why isn't it outputing `2020-02-31`?
- How to output `2020-02-29` using DateTime? (Last day of the month).

```php
$date = new DateTime("2020-01-31");
echo $date->modify("+1 month")->format("Y-m-d"); // 2020-03-02
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP `DateTime::modify("+n month")` adds between 28 to 31 days to the current day, depending of the month and year.

### Solution

I suggest you increment months from the first day of the month by using the `modify` and `format` methods:

```php
// Instanciates the DateTime object.
$date = new DateTime("2020-01-01");

// Adds a month to the date.
$date->modify("+1 month"); // 2020-02-01

// Format the date with "t" (gets the last day of the month).
$date->format("Y-m-t"); // 2020-02-29
```

Incrementing from the first day of the month will **never** raise the *February problem* which is quite a quite common, thinking that PHP DateTime will smartly add a month from `2020-02-29` and output `2020-03-31`.

### Why it happens?

In the [Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar), the [average length of a month](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Month#Julian_and_Gregorian_calendars) is 30.436875 days:

- 30 days in April, June, September and November;
- 31 days in January, March, May, July, August, October and December;
- 28 days or 29 days (in [leap years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year)) in February.

**PHP will add to the current date the exact number of days there is in the given month.**

Thus, PHP will adjust the date after the first increntation if you are incrementing from the
last day of the month.

E.g.:

Let's add a month from the final day of March (31th).

Since the current month (March) has 31 days in it, PHP will increment 31 days to the date. Adding 31 days from `2020-03-31` will result in skipping the whole month of April.

```php
$date = new DateTime("2020-03-31");              // 2020-03-31
echo $date->modify("+1 month")->format("Y-m-d"); // 2020-05-01 | Added 31 days (since March has 31 days).
echo $date->modify("+1 month")->format("Y-m-d"); // 2020-06-01 | Added 31 days (since the new date is May 1st, which is a month with 31 days).
echo $date->modify("+1 month")->format("Y-m-d"); // 2020-07-01 | Added 30 days
```

Now, let's add a month to the final day of April (30th).

We can see that since the next months all have 30+ days in it, final day will stay the same,
**until February of the next year**. Since February always has between 28 and 29 days, adding 31 days to it will pass the month, and resulting date will be March 2nd.

```php
$date = new DateTime("2020-04-30");
echo $date->modify("+1 month")->format("Y-m-d"); // 2020-05-30 | Added 30 days.
echo $date->modify("+1 month")->format("Y-m-d"); // 2020-06-30 | Added 31 days.
echo $date->modify("+1 month")->format("Y-m-d"); // 2020-07-30 | Added 30 days.
// ...
echo $date->modify("+1 month")->format("Y-m-d"); // 2021-01-30 | Added 31 days
echo $date->modify("+1 month")->format("Y-m-d"); // 2021-03-02 | Added 31 days (since January has 31 days).
echo $date->modify("+1 month")->format("Y-m-d"); // 2021-04-02 | Added 31 days (since the new date is March 2nd, which is a month with 31 days).
```

This is why it is recommended to increment months from the first day of the month,
since the *1st* is common to all months.

```php
$date = new DateTime("2020-01-01");              // 2020-01-01
echo $date->modify("+1 month")->format("Y-m-d"); // 2020-02-01 | Added 31 days
echo $date->modify("+1 month")->format("Y-m-d"); // 2020-03-01 | Added 29 days (since 2020 is leap year, yee haw).
echo $date->modify("+1 month")->format("Y-m-d"); // 2020-04-01 | Added 31 days
```

Comment: Thank you. Which other function can I use to add a month a date?

Comment: You could use `date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+n months", strtotime({date})))`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making an assumption that you are programming in php.  If so, the documentation indicates that you will receive the results you are getting [php DateTime::modify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php).

The documentation specifically indicates to "Beware"

Example #2 Beware when adding or subtracting months

```
 <?php
 $date = new DateTime('2000-12-31');

 $date->modify('+1 month');
 echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";

 $date->modify('+1 month');
 echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
 ?>
 The above example will output:

 2001-01-31
 2001-03-03
```

If you just need to move to the end of the next +1 month, what we often do in R is go to the end of the current month and then add +1 day and then go to the end of the month again.  If you know that you are always at the end of the month, then just add +1 day and then go to the end of the month.

Other posts have some additional suggestions in this space
[How to find the last day of the month from date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686724/how-to-find-the-last-day-of-the-month-from-date)

Example from this post:

```
 $date = new DateTime('now');
 $date->modify('last day of this month');
 echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```